# Constructor Injection in Spring / JPA / Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

**New to Spring and JPA**

I have a following controller class

```
public class RegisterStudent{
    private StudentInfo studentInfo;
    private RegisterStudentHelper studentHelper;

    public  void registerStudentProcess(String name,String regNo,String course)
    {
       // // Creating an Instance of StudentInfo Class
        studentInfo = new StudentInfo();
        studentInfo.setName(name);
        studentInfo.setRegNo(regNo);
        studentInfo.setCourse(course);

        // set the StudentInfo to the RegisterStudentHelper constructor
        studentHelper = new RegisterStudentHelper(studentInfo);
        studentHelper.doRegisterStudentProcess();
    }   
}
```

I am trying to convert the same model while using Spring , JPA & hibernate which will look like this

```
    @Controller
    public class RegisterStudent{
            @Autowired
            private StudentInfo studentInfo;
            @Autowired
            private RegisterStudentHelper studentHelper;

            public  void registerStudentProcess(String name,String regNo,String course)
        {

            studentInfo.setName(name);
            studentInfo.setRegNo(regNo);
            studentInfo.setCourse(course);

            studentHelper = new RegisterStudentHelper(studentInfo);
            studentHelper.doRegisterStudentProcess();
    }
}
```

How can i use Annotations to set studentInfo to registerStudentHelper constructor ?

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated .

Comment: Please first fix the typos and the indentation of the code. Then stick to the Java naming conventions (class names uppercase, method names lowercase), then post the question again. Note that a controller is a stateless class by definition.

Comment: Generally speaking, Spring doesn't require anything special--just make a constructor that takes the dependencies as arguments.

Comment: @Roland illig my apologies.i have corrected it now..can you elaborate more on controller stateless class ?

Comment: by the name of those classes I don't think StudentInfo should be a bean and don't think it should be autowired. also don't instantiate RegisterStudentHelper is you are already injecting it

Answer (score 0):

First follow Roland Illig's comment!

Spring (and some other DI frameworks) allows 3 types of dependency injection:

1.Attribute injection

```
@Autowired
private AnyBeanClazz anyBean;
```

2.Method injection

```
@Autowired
public void injectedMethod(AnyBeanClazz anyBean){
    // Do anything here
}
```

3.Constructor injection

```
class OtherBeanClazz{
    @Autowired
    public OtherBeanClazz(AnyBeanClazz anyBean){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your example, I can assume that StudentInfo is a Value Object and RegisterStudentHelper is Service.
As Value Object contains state so they are not best candidate for Dependency Injection. You should create it as new and pass it as a parameter to doRegisterStudentProcess() method.

I found out this article for your understanding:
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2377-creating-service-objects-and-value-objects-in-a-dependency-injection-di-framework.htm

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code does not makes much sense to me, because in some part you set values on the `StudentInfo`, that would be a Singleton class by default if you are using it as a `@Component` to be injected by Spring.

But, here is the code using constructor injection:

```
@Controller
public class RegisterStudent {

    private RegisterStudentHelper studentHelper;
    private StudentInfo studentInfo;

    @Autowired
    RegisterStudent(StudentInfo studentInfo ) {
        this.studentInfo = studentInfo;
        this.studentHelper = studentHelper;
    }

}
```

You can omit the `@Autowired` if you want, because Spring is smart enough to know that if a `Controller` (or any `@Component`) has only one constructor, he automatically will use inject the depedencies.